# Draw Image in rviz 3D visualization frame

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i look for a simple way to display a static image in the 3D-visualization frame in rviz.

Is it possible to lay a image (a.e. a .png-File) over a plane marker? If yes, how it works?

if no, exist another way to realize it.

Thanks for your answer!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40913/draw-image-in-rviz-3d-visualization-frame/) by [CoderDude69](https://answers.ros.org/users/2998/coderdude69/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about making the image a texture on a flat plane created in Blender or similar, export it to dae then load it into rviz as a mesh resource marker?

http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0